# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'q'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

When I try to filter content with tags I get the following error

```
    2022-10-21 16:05:47,853: Internal Server Error: /tag/tag1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'q'
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/app/app/blog/views.py", line 28, in home
    q= request.GET['q']
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'q'
```

My views.py is

```
def home(request, tag_slug=None):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    # tag post
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        posts = posts.filter(tags__in=[tag])



    #search

    q= request.GET['q']
    if q is not None:
        multiple_q=Q(Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(content__icontains=q))
        posts=Post.objects.filter(multiple_q)


    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts':posts})
```

my urls.py has this URLpatterns

```
...
path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/',views.home, name='post_tag'),
```

The search system works as I intend to but for some reason this is affecting my tag filter. Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: are you calling the URL like `tag/my_tag_slug/?q=something`? cause that error is just saying that `q` isn't in the GET parameters. **Side Note:** it's probably best to do `request.GET.get('q')`, which will return **None** if it's not in the GET.. Instead of just crashing

Comment: `request.GET.get('q')` worked fine now. and btw I was not using `tag/my_tag_slug/?q=something` its in URLS `tag/<slug:tag_slug>/`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No Problem. Just know that if you don't do ~`tag/my_tag_slug/?q=something` than that **q** value will always be None